# X being Y versus X is Y

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I was recently chastised by my supervisor for describing something as *being* something else.

The problem:

> "Species A has genes X1, X2 and X3, Species B has genes Y1 and Y2. Protein X3 being the homolog of Y1"

I was told that *"being"* is plain incorrect but I do not understand why, it reads perfectly fine to me.

The proposed revision was:

> "Protein X3 is the homolog of Protein Y1"

Why is this more correct?

Comment: The objection may be that the present participle normally expresses a current action or state of affairs - i.e., something that is time dependant such as "It is raining".  This does not sit well with an identity such as "X = Y".  Further, "Protein X being the homolog of Protein Y" appears to be a phrase rather than a sentence, and therefore requires completion.

Comment: Your first "sentence" is not a full sentence, as it does not have a finite verb.

Comment: What’s the context?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Species A has genes X1, X2 and X3, Species B has genes Y1 and Y2. Protein X3 being the homolog of Y1.

Comment: As Colin said, the way you’ve used it here, it is not a sentence, but a phrase that can function as part of a sentence; but the punctuation treats it like a sentence. That’s your problem. Also, you should edit clarifications like your comment here into the question itself, rather than leaving it as a comment.

Answer (score -2):

"X being Y helped us narrow down our search."

"X being Y, I don't understand why the numbers won't match."

"X is Y, and that's the truth."

"We concluded that X is Y."